# laravel (10) livewire (3) update entity using wire:model of the object instead auxiliar property

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10, livewire-3

I want bind my livewire component properties directly in the html elements using wire:model, I can make this work with simple elements, but When I try bind a property I get error. Leave explain me better with an example:

This is my current working component. This has 3 auxiliar variables that represent 3 fields in my edit form:

```
class ListShops extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $searchTerm;
    public $currentShop;
    public $showModal = false;

    //Campos de edición
    public $currentName;
    public $currentStatus;
    public $currentRegion;

    public function cancelEditingShop() { $this->showModal = false; }

    public function selectShopToEdit($editingShopId){
        $this->currentShop = Tienda::findOrFail($editingShopId);
        $this->currentName = $this->currentShop->name;
        $this->currentRegion = $this->currentShop->region;
        $this->currentStatus = $this->currentShop->enabled;
        $this->showModal = true;
    }

    public function saveEditingShop(){

        $this->currentShop->name    = $this->currentName;
        $this->currentShop->region  = $this->currentRegion;
        $this->currentShop->enabled = $this->currentStatus;

        $this->currentShop->save();
        $this->currentShop = null;
        $this->showModal = false;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        if($this->searchTerm!=''){
            $this->resetPage();
        }

        $tiendas = Tienda::
            select('id', 'name', 'keyname', 'country_id', 'enabled', 'region')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->searchTerm . '%')
            ->paginate(10);

        return view('livewire.list-shops', ['tiendas' => $tiendas]);
    }
}
```

On my blade.php file I have a html table with a list of shops, and at the end a conditional form that only loads when $currentShop exists. (Currentshops variable exists when you click Edit button and **selectShopToEdit** function executes.

```
@if ($currentShop)
<div class="{{ $showModal ? 'block' : 'hidden' }} fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
    <div >
        <div >
            <div >
                <div>
                    <h3>{{__('shops.edit.country')}}</h3>

                    <div class="relative z-0 w-full group">
                        <input type="text"
                               wire:model="currentName"
                               name="shop_name" id="shop_name"
                               placeholder=" " required/>
                        <label for="shop_name">
                            {{ __('shops.name') }}</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="group">
                    <label for="region" class="sr-only">Region</label>
                    <select id="region" wire:model="currentRegion" required>
                        <option {{ $currentShop->region == 'AM' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="AM">{{ __('shops.america') }}</option>
                        <option {{ $currentShop->region == 'EU' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="EU">{{ __('shops.europe') }}</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="group my-4">
                    <fieldset >
                        <legend class="sr-only">Status</legend>

                        <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
                            <input id="status_enabled" wire:model="currentStatus" type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked />
                            <label for="status_enabled">
                                {{ __('shops.online') }}
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
                            <input id="status_disabled" wire:model="currentStatus" type="radio" name="status" value="0" />
                            <label for="status_disabled">
                                {{ __('shops.offline') }}
                            </label>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                {{-- Botones del modal --}}
                <button wire:click="saveEditingShop" >
                    {{ __('shops.button.save') }}
                </button>
                <button wire:click="cancelEditingShop" >
                    {{ __('shops.button.close') }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

I want simplify and use my $currentShop instance instead the 3 auxiliar variables. I tried something like this (Deleting the use of these three vars in the component and using currentShop.xxx in the wire:model):

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Tienda;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ListShops extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $searchTerm;
    public $currentShop;
    public $showModal = false;


    public function cancelEditingShop() { $this->showModal = false; }

    public function selectShopToEdit($editingShopId){
        $this->currentShop = Tienda::findOrFail($editingShopId);
        $this->showModal = true;
    }

    public function saveEditingShop(){
        $this->currentShop->save();
        $this->currentShop = null;
        $this->showModal = false;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        if($this->searchTerm!=''){
            $this->resetPage();
        }

        $tiendas = Tienda::
            select('id', 'name', 'keyname', 'country_id', 'enabled', 'region')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->searchTerm . '%')
            ->paginate(10);

        return view('livewire.list-shops', ['tiendas' => $tiendas]);
    }
}
```

For reduce code, is the same that initial example but with this wire:model settings:

```
<input type="text"
       wire:model="currentShop.name"
       name="shop_name" id="shop_name"
       placeholder=" " required />

...

<select id="region" wire:model="currentShop.region" required >

...

 <input id="status_enabled" wire:model="currentShop.enabled" type="radio" name="status"
                                       value="1" />
```

but this error produces when I open the modal (at javascript console, not error in laravel or php components):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`

So the problem is when my input model is getting **currentShop.name** my component **currentShop** element is not initialized. But this component is not loaded in the html until I press in the edit button and the "**selectShopToEdit**" is executed that is where I am initiating this variable. So, I am confused on why currentShop is not initialized at this time when in the first example the variables $currentName, etc.. are working and initied in the same component function.